# Built in method for testing either nil or empty array?

Tags: ruby

How can I tell if an array is either empty or nil?

Comment: Array cannot be nil. Variable can be nil or an Array or whatever else. But an Array can be only an Array. You can use `blank?`.

Answer (score 54):

Without Rails or ActiveSupport,

```
array.to_a.empty?
```

Comment: @fl00r Thanks. This is actually, I believe, is the purpose of the built in method `Array#to_a`. I can't think of other uses of it.

Comment: I believe it is `NilClass#to_a` method also :)

Comment: Splat also works here and I sometimes use it for this purpose: 
`[*arr].empty?`

Comment: @Michael I see. That's elegant.

Comment: In Rails if you use `blank?`, it will check both .nil? and .empty?

Comment: Beautiful solution.. This works even with nil: `nil.to_a.empty?` still resolves to true.

Answer (score 37):

There's no built-in Ruby method that does this, but `ActiveSupport`'s `blank` does:

```
>> require "active_support/core_ext/object/blank" #=> true
>> nil.blank? #=> true
>> [].blank? #=> true
```

Comment: Careful with this one. `[" "].blank?` and `[""].blank?` return false.

Comment: Nothing to be careful about. You're calling `blank?` on an instance of array and said array is neither empty nor nil. If that's not what you want use `[''].all?(&:blank?)` instead.

Comment: @KrisKhaira If you want to catch empty Strings as well (and are using Rails) you can also use `[ " ", "" ].compact_blank.empty? #=> true`. I actually like @Michael Kohl's `.all?(&:blank?)` better if you don't want to modify the array, though.

Answer (score 13):

You can just use the  [Array#empty?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000235) and [Object#nil?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001007) methods in conjunction with an OR.

```
arr.nil? || arr.empty?
```

This will return true of array is empty or the array value is nil.

Comment: I know of those, I was hoping there was a single call that did both (those neg. votes are not from me)

Comment: @aromero: The downvote was probably because if `arr` really is `nil`, the `empty?` check will raise a `NoMethodError`. If you reverse the order it's fine, because the logical expression will short-circuit.

Comment: Maybe you have to test arry.nil? first

Comment: Very true. Changed per your comment.

Comment: @Michael Kohl, I've figured it out, sorry. Your reason is more solid

Answer (score 5):

To check whether array is empty one can use '**empty?**' inbuilt method as follows,

> array.empty?  # returns true/false

To check whether array is nil (If not initialized or set to nil)

> array.nil?  # returns true/false